# Compiler cannot infer if an object of `impl <trait>` has impled another trait in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Consider I have a trait `A` and I have lots of *structs*(e.g. `X`) impled `A`. Then I write many small functions(return these structs) to abstract my logic. However, the return type of these functions can be huge and too
complex to write(like `Chain<Map<'a, (i32, u8), u16, Enumerate<Filter<'a, u8, vec::MoveItems<u8>>>>, SkipWhile<'a, u16, Map<'a, &u16, u16, slice::Items<u16>>>>`), so I used `impl A` instead since as far as I know, `impl <trait>s` are still static dispatched:

```
trait A {...}
struct X {...}
impl A for X {...}
fn func_to_return_impl_A() -> impl A {...}
```

Now the problem is that recently I want to impl my *structs* to another trait `B`. Whenever I want to use values returned by my small functions as: `func_to_return_impl_A(...).method_of_trait_B(...)`, the compiler complained: `no implementation for impl A <method of trait B> ...`. Moreover, I cannot simply rewrite the return types as `impl A + B` since trait `B` may also contain complex generic type or associated types which I cannot write myself:

```
impl B for X {...}

fn some_func() {
  func_to_return_impl_A().method_of_trait_B(...) //error: no implementation for impl A <method of trait B> ...
}
```

The only way to avoid this I can think of is to make another wrapper to wrap all my structs and impl it to trait `B`, but as the model getting more complex, this would be hard to maintain. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: If you are writing a function that returns `impl A` and then finding yourself needing to call a method that belongs to `trait B` on the returned value, it sounds like your code is not factored correctly.

Comment: *"I cannot simply rewrite the return types as `impl A + B` since trait `B` may also contain complex generic type or associated types which I cannot write myself"* - can you elaborate on this? In order to call `B` methods you have to tell the type system that you're returning a `B`.

Comment: @harmic Yes, but if I instead write the complex struct type, everything would work. I want to make use of the flexibility of Rust's trait system and avoid complex type signatures at the same time. How should I design my program?

Comment: @kmdreko Consider the trait `B` is `std::ops::Shr`, then the type `Rhs` cannot be inferred simply because the returned type has no information on how its value will be used in the future...

Comment: `Rhs` is [defaulted to self](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3484968af04767154082e69510cfdda)... or do you mean `Rhs` is some other type that you don't want to name? if so, how is the compiler (or user for that matter) supposed to know what you can `>>` with?

Comment: @kmdreko Suppose I want impl `Shr` as: `impl<T> Shr<T> for <some struct>`, then the compiler should check type whenever I use `x >> y` and make sure this is safe. I tried this for pure struct instead of `impl trait` and this does work.

Comment: I see now. Unfortunately, if you're obscuring the concrete type by returning `impl`, you *must* be explicit about everything your returned object can do. You can make super traits to organize it a little better but the effect is the same. This case in particular may be possible in the future with generic associated types, but I'm not sure if that will be applicable.

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you! I think I've figured out the solution since `impl trait` can be part of a generic type, I can just make a struct `Wrapper<impl A>` and impl `Wrapper<T>` to trait `A` and `B`. Finally, everything works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I've find the ad-hoc solution for my problem: additional `Wrapper`:

```
struct Wrapper<P: A> {
    p: P
}

impl<P: A> A for Wrapper<P> {...}
impl<P: A> B for Wrapper<P> {...}

fn func_to_return_impl_A() -> Wrapper<impl A> {...}
```

Then I can use methods of trait `B`:

```
func_to_return_impl_A().method_of_trait_B(...);
```